# How to pass null value in RESTful way (GET filtering)? As an empty value or as 'null'?

Tags: rest, api, http, design-patterns

I want to retrieve all installations that weren't removed yet.

Should I do this like that:

```
/installations?removedOn=
```

or

```
/installations?removedOn=null
```

or maybe in some other way?

```
/installations?removed=false
```

Despite the fact, that something tells me that `removed=false` looks better, removedOn` may be more practical because later I could query installations that are removed in particular timeframe using the same param.

Answer (score 2):

REST doesn't care what spelling you use for your URI.

- `/installationsThatArentRemovedYet`
- `/installations?neverRemoved`
- `/f784d74e-b8bf-4832-9297-03816e5b4936`

Any of these are *fine*, as far as REST is concerned.

It follows that these are also fine

- `/installations?removedOn=`
- `/installations?removedOn=null`
- `/installations?removed=false`

One important thing to keep in mind is that the URI should still *work* even if your underlying implementation changes.  So you want stable semantics, with your controller having the responsibility of mapping those semantics to your current implementation.